# processing web export does not work on the web

Tags: javascript, web, processing

I heard the issue of multiple broswsers not supporting web export for processing javaScript. But I tried 3, MS edge, chrome and firefox it does not work in any of them. here is the link for my sketch.

http://www.azberserkfan.web44.net/electionTest/

You can also check the source code for the sketch in the same link if you ant to But I am certain that you do not need that step.

My sketch shows you results of the elections of America from 1988 to 2008 and needless to say it is based on inaccurate data. It allows to chose the category of voters and the year.

I tried to add the preloader comment since im using a csv to read data but it still does not work.

preloader comment:
/* @pjs preload="file1.png","file2.png","file3.jgp"; */

Comment: I get the obvious out of the way: are the browsers updated and does it throw errors (hit F12)?

Comment: Yes the browsers are updated. When I hit f12 it shows one error which says class election is not defined, which is weird because the java runs smoothly.

Comment: Saying I'm not fluent in p5 is an understatement, so another question: Do you need to "import" multiple javascript files?

Comment: Im not using p5 just to clear that out. I'm using the web export in the java script mode which you can download in processing. The only javascript file  that is necessary is the processing.js...which the sketch automatically creates when you export the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please post your code (as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in the post itself.

Secondly, you need to familiarize yourself with the JavaScript console. That's where any errors you're getting will show up. In most browsers you can press the `F12` key and then go to the console tab. There you'll see this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: elections is not defined
```

So apparently you're using a variable that you haven't defined. Note that the translation process from "Java mode" Processing to Processing.js isn't always smooth, so you might have to look at the generated JavaScript to understand exactly why it's throwing this error.

If you still can't get it figured out, then please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. Please note that this should **not** be your full sketch; it should be just a few lines of code that we can copy and paste to see the same behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will try my best to follow your advise.